# How can I get the processor to work asynchronously in inbound-endpoint in Mule?

Tags: asynchronous, mule

I am new to Mule and i am working on a company project. I have many inbound-endpoints defined in XML in a single flow. I am trying to get the processor "scbProcessor" that processes the response to work asynchronously in the inbound-endpoint.

I tried to just wrap the processor in `<async></async>` but it gives the error: "Invalid content was found starting with element 'async'". Then I tried to make it sub-flow then reference to flow, which gave the same error.

Code:

```
    <flow name="scb-services">
            <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source inbounds">

                <https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${httpInbound.secure.host}"
                                        port="${httpInbound.secure.port}" doc:name="HTTPS QWE Service (Deprecated)"
                                        path="${httpInbound.qwe.contextRoot}/${auto.external.serviceName}"
                                        responseTimeout="${service.qwe.auto.timeout}" connector-ref="httpsConnector">
                    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
                    <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="PUBLIC"/>                        
                    <response>              
                        <set-variable variableName="outgoingFromESBToClientDate"
                                      value="#[new org.mule.el.datetime.DateTime()]"
                                      doc:name="Register Outgoing date from ESB to Client"/>
                        <processor ref="scbProcessor" doc:name="SCB Logging Processor"/>
                    </response>
                </https:inbound-endpoint>
                .
                .
            </composite-source>
    </flow>
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `exchange-pattern="request-response"` to `exchange-pattern="one-way"`to send the messages asynchronously. You can see it in the official documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.6/http-transport-reference

Alternatively, you can use a queue in between. Send the message to queue as soon as it is received and then process it after reading it from the queue.